# Find all PHP files in the current folder that contain a string

Tags: linux, grep

How could I show names of all PHP files in the current folder that contain the string "Form.new" in a Linux system?

I have tried `grep "Form.new" .`

Comment: The `.` matches any characters, you'll need to escape it.

Comment: @LaughDonor Well, yes and no. Formally that is correct. However the `.` does also match the literal `.`, so it _would_ match all desired matches, though possibly more, by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search recursive or using`*` instead of `.`, depending of whether you want to search only file right inside that directory or also in deeper levels. So:

```
grep -r "Form\.new" .
```

or

```
grep "Form\.new" *
```

Comment: use the handy params `-rn` to also print out filename and line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your PHP files have a `.php` extension, the following will do the trick:

```bsh
grep "Form\.new" *.php
```

Like @LaughDonor mentioned, it's good practise to escape the dot; otherwise, dot is interpreted as “any character” by grep. "Form.new" also matches "Form_new", "Form-new", "Form:new", "FormAnew", etc.